# SonarQube Code Coverage tools for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, maven, sonarqube, code-coverage

I am new to JavaScript and Currently in our project, We are writing unit test cases from scratch. Our project is fully written in JavaScript and uses maven for building. Initially we planned to use Jasmine to write unit tests. But We are not able to find promising plugins exclusively for JavaScript to generate and integrate code coverage reports with SonarQube ? We tried few plugins like Saga with sonar-maven-plugin. But SonarQube shows 0% code coverage.
Please suggest some of the promising plugins/tools to generate and integrate JavaScript code coverage reports with SonarQube? Please help with complete working examples/Code snippets for the same ?

**(We don't use node.js at all)**

Comment: May be this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997541/javascript-code-coverage-in-sonar

Comment: @SouravAtta This does not have any useful info about plugin details and its configuration. It just have info about lcov file path. we need info on how to generate lcov files for code coverage.

Comment: If you have gone through the answers properly of the link shared in previous comment, it has been mentioned there you can use **Karma** to produce lcov.info

Comment: @SouravAtta : Looks Karma needs node.js. we don't use node.js at all. Please provide any documentation/blogs where karma can be set up for pure java script.